# Why can't "TransformedDistribution" give a result but finding the probability first and then the derivative can?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, transformation

```mathematica
PDF[TransformedDistribution[Sin[X], 
   Distributed[X, ProbabilityDistribution[2*x/(Pi^2), {x, 0, Pi}]]], 
  y] // Simplify
```

produces

```
PDF[TransformedDistribution[Sin[X], 
  X \[Distributed] 
   ProbabilityDistribution[(
    2 \[FormalX])/\[Pi]^2, {\[FormalX], 0, \[Pi]}]], y]
```

[image]

But

```mathematica
D[Probability[Sin[X] < y, 
  Distributed[X, ProbabilityDistribution[2   x/(Pi^2), {x, 0, Pi}]]],
  y]
```

can produce
$$\left\{\eqalign{&0,\,&y<0\cr &\frac{2}{\pi\sqrt{1-y^2}},\,0<&y<1\cr &0,\,&y>1\cr &{\rm Indeterminate,}\,&{\rm True} }\right.$$
[image]

Why doesn't `TransformedDistribution` work but finding the probability first and then the derivative can give the right result?

Comment: I wish I knew the answer.  Note that using `Sin[X] <= y` rather than `Sin[X] < y` just returns the *Mathematica* code.  Sometimes using a distribution in *Mathematica*'s repertoire works.  But using the equivalent `PowerDistribution[1/Pi, 2]` doesn't work either.

Comment: @JimB So, there is a bug that `{x, a, b}` always means $a\le x\le b$, so users can't make a $a<x<b$ by  `{x, a, b}`  style.

Comment: A desired feature not implemented is not a bug.  But writing to Wolfram, Inc. with the issue would seem to be the next step (unless someone else here has other suggestions). 
 At least in this case you have a workaround.

Comment: @JimB But now, I think it isn't what as you said. Try `PDF[TransformedDistribution[Sin[X], 
   Distributed[X, 
    ProbabilityDistribution[2*x/(Pi^2), {0.1, 0, 0.99*Pi}]]], 
  y] // Simplify` will return the code too.

Comment: It's too late at night for me as I'm not seeing how your example contradicts anything I've written.

Comment: @JimB Thanks. I misunderstood your comment earlier.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question but rather another alternative to use when `TransformedDistribution` doesn't work.

The pdf of $X$ is

```
pdfx[x_] := Piecewise[{{2 x/π^2, 0 <= x <= π}}]
```

The desired transformation ($Y=\sin(X)$) is not a 1-to-1 transformation (as for every $Y$ value there are two $X$ values) but is 1-to-1 in two separate segments.  First we find the inverse functions for each of the two segments (meaning $0\leq X < \pi/2$ and $\pi/2 \leq X \leq \pi$).

```
sol1 = Simplify[x /. Solve[{Sin[x] == y, 0 <= x < π/2}, x][[1]], Assumptions -> 0 < y < 1]
(* ArcSin[y] *)
sol2 = Simplify[x /. Solve[{Sin[x] == y, π/2 <= x < π}, x][[1]], Assumptions -> 0 < y < 1]
(* π - ArcSin[y] *)
```

Now we construct the pdf for $Y=\sin(X)$:

```
pdfy = Simplify[pdfx[sol1] Abs[D[sol1, y]] + pdfx[sol2] Abs[D[sol2, y]] // PiecewiseExpand,
  Assumptions -> 0 <= y <= 1]
(* 2/(π Sqrt[1 - y^2]) *)
```

The following link has more details on this approach:  https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/book/export/html/772.

Comment: `PDF[TransformedDistribution[Sin[X] + 2 X, 
   Distributed[X, ProbabilityDistribution[2*x/(Pi^2), {x, 0, Pi}]]], 
  y] // Simplify` does not work too, though `Sin[X]+2X` is one-to-one map.

Comment: @user64494 I made no claim that `TransformedDistribution` should work if the there was a one-to-one map.  For example, `Cos[X]` is a one-to-one map for $0<X<\pi$ but it doesn't work either.